# Locate an element in selenium having only href

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a Href element

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary sub_count" href="http://10.144.97.192:8090/JEP/HQCreation">
<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
</a>
```

in selenium.
I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://10.144.97.192:8090/JEP/HQCreation']")).click();
```

And getting following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An
>   invalid or illegal selector was specified

Kindly help

Comment: I believe you can use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href='http://10.144.97.192:8090/JEP/HQCreation']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use cssselector instead of xpath. You please try with the below code

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='http://10.144.97.1‌​92:8090/JEP/HQCreati‌​on']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='http://10.144.97.1‌​92:8090/JEP/HQCreati‌​on']")).click();
```

as you have asked a very basic question you can follow  https://www.testingexcellence.com/click-link-href-value-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

To click the `href` you can use the following :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary sub_count' and contains(@href,'/JEP/HQCreation')]/span[@class='fa fa-plus']")).click();
```